# How to get Data from AsyncStorage to any other screen and then use it in fetching records from API?

Tags: react-native, expo

```
.then((response) => response.json())

            .then((responseJson) => {
                console.log(responseJson);
                if (responseJson.res_status == "200") {
                    console.log(responseJson.res_data);                 

                    onSave = async () => {


                        try {
                            await AsyncStorage.setItem("key", JSON.stringify(responseData));
                            Alert.alert('Saved', 'Successful');
                        } catch (error) {
                            Alert.alert('Error', 'There was an error.')
                        }
                    }
                            this.props.navigation.navigate('Dashboard')
```

This is my code to save Data in AsyncStorage. Now I want this Data on 'Dashboard' and also in every screen. I am getting Data Login API so, I want to save it's Login Details over the app and use it whenever I required.

Comment: what is the error you are getting? you are storing perfectly.

Comment: Sir I am storing successfully. But I want to get this data on other screens. I do not know the process. Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get your data in ComponentDidMount...

Function for getting Array List:

```
getArraySharedDataPrefence = async (key) => {
   try {
      const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem(key)
      if (value !== null) {
         return JSON.parse(value);
      }
   } catch (e) {
      return '';

   }
   return '';
}

function getArraySharedPreferenceValue(key) {
   const arrayList= await getArraySharedDataPrefence(key);
   return arrayList;
}
```

Call this Function in ComponentDidMount:

```
    getArraySharedPreferenceValue("YourKey").then(res => {
      if (res === 'isRecipeOn') {

      } else {

      }
    }).catch();
```

Answer (score 3):

This is how you can get asyncStorage data

```
_retrieveData = async () => {
  try {
    const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('key');
    if (value !== null) {
      console.log(value);
    }
  } catch (error) {
    // Error retrieving data
  }
};
```

see [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/asyncstorage)

Comment: Can I use it in any screen throughout the App??

Comment: @HimanshuMishra yes you can use it in any screen go through the documentation

Answer (score 0):

So if you want to get the value stored in async storage, its pretty simple,

Suppose you want to use it in HomeScreen and inside componentDidMount you want to fetch the value so ,

```
class HomeScreen extends Component {

async componentDidMount(){
const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('key');
}

}
```

im here adding the name of variable stored and in your case it was key , since you did await `AsyncStorage.setItem("key", JSON.stringify(responseData));` and first variable was key which is the variable named stored in async storage.

So in future whenever you want to set , do it by

```
await AsyncStorage.setItem("variable-name", value);
```

and to fetch

```
await AsyncStorage.getItem('variable-name');
```

Hope it helps. feel free for doubts.